# Is there a thorough published skills tree for mathematics?

Tags: education

**UPDATE**:  There is no actual graph or tree which I have found, but for anyone looking there are some usable assets which are discussed here:
[Is there a tag/competence classification for mathematics education?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/318/is-there-a-tag-competence-classification-for-mathematics-education)

**ORIGINAL**:  I would like to find a good skills tree for mathematics, so that I can learn the prerequisite knowledge and skills for any given set of skills.  For example, if one wants to learn algebra, one should have fluency with basic math operations like addition and multiplication, a solid understanding of fractions, percents, and decimals, ratios and proportions, et al.

Is there such a published skills tree for mathematics?  I have been unable to find one online with a reasonable search effort.

Comment: This question may be better suited for matheducators.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It would help to know what this is for. For example, if this is for your own pursuit of some subject in mathematics, why wouldn't you just look over the preface (which often provides prerequisites for the book) or table of contents of the book you're interested in to see whether it would work for you? If it's for a school's (or district's or city's or state's or country's) math teaching purposes, then pretty much every organization has their own "skills list" ([typical example](https://hunterschools.myschoolapp.com/ftpimages/602/download/download_1966659.pdf) I found in less than 10 seconds).

Comment: In grad school I got embroiled in a rather bitter dispute online about whether such a tree was even possible to produce. (Most of the juicy bits are hard to find nowadays, which is probably for the best for all involved. But a more civil branch of the conversation is preserved on my blog: https://thousandmaths.tumblr.com/post/163532613474/homieomorphism-people-often-act-like-math-is-a)

Comment: Everyone writes books and blog posts, but math explainers tend not to design brilliant, efficient math curriculums. We need more of that.

Comment: This reminds me of an infographic I found called [The List](https://i.imgur.com/FXv61BG.png)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro this is for helping my children explore math efficiently when they want to study something specific which is beyond their current ability.  I admit I sometimes would like to have this for my own intellectual pursuits as well.

Comment: @Dan that comment was helpful.  I've edited the question to reflect what I found there.  My question could probably be considered a duplicate if I moved it to the other site.  Should I delete it or leave it here as a pointer to the one on the educator's site?  Thoughts?